# localization of module of constant rank is again of constant rank

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $A$ be commutative ring with unit and $M$ module over $A$ such that rank (the smallest number of generators) of $M_{P}$ over $A_{P}$  is constant for every $P \in \mathrm{Spec}(A) $. Does this property holds for module $M_{P}$ over $A_{P}$?

It seems to be true but I can't find any way of proving it without getting my hands dirty i.e. referring to  construction of localization instead of using universal property of localization. Any hints greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that would make this easy is that $\mathrm{Spec}(A_P) \subseteq \mathrm{Spec}(A)$.

Algebraically, the prime ideals of $A_P$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the ideals of $A$ contained in $P$.  Furthermore, if $Q \subseteq P$, there is a natural isomorphism $(A_P)_{Q_P} \cong A_{Q}$.

Comment: And a natural isomorphism $(M_P)_{Q_P} \cong M_{Q}$ ;)